# Azure WebJob - General Questions

Tags: azure, schedule, azure-webjobs

Background:
I need to deply a program that runs every 24h, this program generates a xml file, which needs to be saved to Azure Files.

So based on that i have several questions:

- Is Azure Storage obligatory if i'm trying to deploy a scheduled web job? Or can it be done without?
- Is it possible to write to Azure File within the web job?(Azure FTP)
- Is a Web Job the right kind to use?

Answer (score 1):

Azure web jobs is a great choice for programs that need to run on a schedule. Here are answers to your specifics:

1) No, a web job can be a console application, PowerShell script or anything that executes really. There is no obligation to use any other Azure features when using a web job other than the 'app service plan' in which it will be contained. You can upload a zip containing your web job directly within the portal, no dependency on azure storage

2) Not quite sure what you mean by 'azure file', but if you are writing a console application, you can certainly use the azure SDK to write files to an azure storage account. This is the typical way you'd output files and logs from a web job

3) If you need something that runs in the cloud on a schedule without human intervention, then yes an Azure web job is a great choice

Comment: Keam that was a great answer! :) With 2. i mean i have files on the azure FTP (in wwwroot) where i'd like to write to

Comment: Hi Thoor, glad it helped (please mark as an answer if you can you help increase my rep :) ). To write to wwwroot on your website you can use standard FTP (search on stack overflow for how to do that), or you can write to azure storage via the azure sdk.